# Searching docx Files in python

Tags: python, module, docx

I am trying to use the python-docx module to search docx files for specific strings:

https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx

But for some reason none of the functions I try to use within the module seem to be working (opendocx, search, etc). I have installed the module and have imported it in my script so I can't figure out what's going wrong. For example though when I try to use opendocx() I get an error saying the module has no attribute 'opendocx'

Other people seem to be able to use this module fine, am I missing something obvious?

EDIT:

Here is the code where I am trying to use the doc:

```
def parseFile2(filename):
    document = opendocx(filename)
    for key in SEARCH_STRINGS:
        if search(document, key):
            return True
```

The filename is passed in from another function with a full path and again the error I am getting is that the module has no attribute opendocx

Answer (score 0):

You may be doing `import modulename` rather than `from modulename import class`. This can often lead to the behavior you're seeing. For example:

```
>>> import math
>>> sqrt(64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(64)
8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am indeed just using import docx rather than what you said but I've just tried from docx import opendocx and it now says it cant import name opendocx, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at the documentation of the module you're not using the Document class of the module.

```
from docx import Document

def parseFile2(filename):
    document = Document(filename)
    for key in SEARCH_STRINGS:
        if search(document, key): # dont know if this part works, cause i didn't install the module
            return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works, looking back on it I was using old documentation before docx was integrated into the OpenXML project. However in the new documentation there does not seem to be a function that allows for a simple search of a document....